# Intel Centrino 1000 not working on an hp dm4t

Tags: 11.10, wireless, hp, intel, centrino

I've an HP dm4t laptop with an Intel Centrino Wireless 1000 card. Everything was working fine on Natty but when I upgraded to Oneiric, the wireless (specifically connectin to WPA2 Personal) stopped working - I would enter the password and it would try to connect but fail.

Since then, I've tried everything including a complete reinstall of the system (along with reformatting the hard drive) to no avail. Oddly enough though, when I run the installation procedure and it asks me to connect to the internet, the wireless works fine. It also doesn't seem to be a kernel issue as I installed Natty with the newest 3.x kernel and the wireless worked fine.

Thanks

PS - I have only tested with WPA2 since that's all that I've available but it's possible the wireless would work ok with other types of networks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wifi for Centrino Wireless-N 1000 Intel Corporation (HP pavillion dm4 - 2070us) is not working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74692/wifi-for-centrino-wireless-n-1000-intel-corporation-hp-pavillion-dm4-2070us)

Answer (score 1):

Refer the following link, you will get a work around to your problem.

[Wifi for Centrino Wireless-N 1000 Intel Corporation (HP Pavilion dm4 - 2070us) is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74692/wifi-for-centrino-wireless-n-1000-intel-corporation-hp-pavillion-dm4-2070us)