# Wifi disabled for Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1000 Intel in 12.04

Tags: wireless, kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wifi for Centrino Wireless-N 1000 Intel Corporation (HP pavillion dm4 - 2070us) is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74692/wifi-for-centrino-wireless-n-1000-intel-corporation-hp-pavillion-dm4-2070us)

Laptop model - HP- dm4 - 2070.

I had faced the same problem for wireless being disabled in case of 11.10. It had to do with the new kernel.  I thought with 12.04 this problem will be handled but the problem persists. Is there no way to get the wireless working except for the way mentioned in the following link ??

[Wifi for Centrino Wireless-N 1000 Intel Corporation (HP Pavilion dm4 - 2070us) is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74692/wifi-for-centrino-wireless-n-1000-intel-corporation-hp-pavillion-dm4-2070us)

Output for  sudo lshw -class network

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Network controller
   product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:c2500000-c2501fff

*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet
   vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: c0
   serial: 2c:41:38:07:f3:e3
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.0-NAPI duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.116 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:43 memory:c1400000-c143ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
```

Output for dmesg | grep iwl

```
[   14.742886] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[   14.742897] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   14.743013] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: pci_resource_len = 0x00002000
[   14.743016] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: pci_resource_base = ffffc90000c78000
[   14.743018] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: HW Revision ID = 0x0
[   14.743119] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: irq 42 for MSI/MSI-X
[   14.743161] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 1000 BGN, REV=0x6C
[   14.743229] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[   14.765147] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: device EEPROM VER=0x15d, CALIB=0x6
[   14.765151] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Device SKU: 0X50
[   14.765154] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Valid Tx ant: 0X1, Valid Rx ant: 0X3
[   14.765907] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 0 802.11a channels
[   14.912840] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode' failed.
[   14.914254] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-1000-4.ucode' failed.
[   14.915718] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-1000-3.ucode' failed.
[   14.916986] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-1000-2.ucode' failed.
[   14.919391] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-1000-1.ucode' failed.
[   14.919445] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
[   14.919783] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: PCI INT A disabled
[ 2868.960807] Modules linked in: snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_idt rfcomm bnep bluetooth parport_pc ppdev binfmt_misc hid_logitech_dj usbhid hid joydev snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_rawmidi snd_seq_midi_event snd_seq hp_wmi sparse_keymap hp_accel lis3lv02d input_polldev snd_timer snd_seq_device wmi iwlwifi snd mac80211 i915 cfg80211 rts_pstor(C) drm_kms_helper drm uvcvideo videodev psmouse soundcore mei(C) v4l2_compat_ioctl32 mac_hid serio_raw snd_page_alloc i2c_algo_bit video lp parport atl1c
```