# HP Pavilion dv4-3029tx Wireless

Tags: 12.04, wireless, laptop, hp-pavilion, centrino

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wifi disabled for Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1000 Intel in 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128028/wifi-disabled-for-intel-centrino-wireless-n-1000-intel-in-12-04)

I just bought an HP dv4-3029tx and installed Ubuntu 12.04 on it.  It has a centrino wireless-n 1030 card.  I have no problems with wired connections, nor with connecting to my smartphone's mobile hotspot, but with my home wireless connection just won't work, it's just impossible to make a connection.  Just to add to the mystery is the fact that several other devices I own are connecting flawlessly to my home wireless network so the home wireless isn't the issue.

I've downloaded the appropriate driver from intellinuxwireless.org and extracted it to /lib/firmware but with no improvement, any ideas?

Comment: You don't have to install any drivers because drivers for your wireless card are included in kernel. [Read hare](http://intellinuxwireless.org/?p=iwlwifi).

Comment: thanks, i thought that might be the case but i also thought it might be worth a try.

Comment: solved using: 

    sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
    sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1

from http://askubuntu.com/questions/128028/wifi-disabled-for-intel-centrino-wireless-n-1000-intel-in-12-04/

Comment: this thread is helpful: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1966860&page=4